# Parsing string to datetime inside datetimepicker C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, oracle11g, datetimepicker

I have a C# app connected to Oracle Database, and a table like this
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzRL9.png)

I created a MouseDoubleClick event that selects the data into the fields below, and I want to display the date into the first datetimepicker like its shown on the picture. In Database that particular date is set to Varchar, so the problem pops up that I need to parse it in order for it to be shown inside this datetimepicker. So how exactly am I about to do that parsing?

MouseDoubleClick Event:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
comboBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
dateTimePicker1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
```

Error pops up pops up within the datetimepciker line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be assigning to the "Value" property of the DateTimePicker class.

In addition, you'll need to parse the date into a DateTime object before you can pass it in. Something like this should do the trick:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedValue = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
comboBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

String s = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
//culture is set to british based on your date format
DateTimeFormatInfo culture = (new CultureInfo("en-GB")).DateTimeFormat;
DateTime dt; //declare variable to hold our datetime
//since this is DB data, use "tryparse" as it may not be formatted properly
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, culture, DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
    dateTimePicker1.Value = dt;
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to this, but error I get is that I'm missing directive or assembly reference for DateTimeFormatInfo, CultureInfo and DateTimeStyles. I don't know what reference should I add in order for VS to recognize this code

Comment: I used System.Globalization reference and it's now working. Thanks a lot :)